# DPPS on older version GCC

Tags: c, assembly, sse

Hei!

I need to optimize some matrix multiplication code in c, and I'm doing it using SSE vector instructions. I also found that there exists SSE4.1 that already has instruction for dot-product, dpps.

The problem is that on machine this software is supposed to work there is an old version of gcc installed (4.1.2), which has no support for SSE4.1, but it has a processor that supports it (don't ask me why gcc version is older than processor...). So I cannot use _mm_dp_ps function.

I was playing around a bit with adding some assembler code to c. The problem is I have never before used assembler code so it's really confusing. Also is it more efficient to write all the code that is dealing with vector instructions in assembler?

So I am asking here if there are any other ways how to use dpps instruction, and if it is even worth using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Frankly, I do not see the problem. From your description, it seems that the machine on which the final code needs to be executed supports SSE4.1 and `DPPS`. Therefore, once your source code - including the instrinsic (or assembly) -  is compiled, it can be executed on this machine. You would only have to get your code compiled with a newer version of the compiler, either by installing a newer version on the machine you are talking about or by compiling on a different machine and then copying the executable to the machine it'll have to run on.

As to whether optimisation with `DPPS` is worth the effort, that will depend on your code (i.e., how much potential for optimisation there is -- you should profile thoroughly to find out where your bottlenecks are) and how important performance actually is in this specific case (i.e. is it worth *your* time?; time is money)

Obviously, if you have little assembly experience, implementing your routine in asm, or maybe even just writing your own asm wrapper function around `DPPS`, becomes less attractive. (But it is certainly possible to do.)